# Convert Simple list into html Select list

Tags: html

I want to convert this list. All the data stored into .txt file.

```
one
two
three
```

into this format

```
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
etc
```

thanks

Comment: "Convert" using what platform / program / technology?

Comment: And who *upvotes* a completely unanswerable question like this? We really have an upvote inflation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP:

```
<?php

  $fc = file_get_contents(FILE_PATH);
  $lines = explode("\n", $fc);

  $html = '<select>';
  foreach($lines as $line)
     $html .= '<option value="' . $line . '">' . $line . '</option>';

  $html .= '</select>';
  echo $html;
```

**Note**: You cannot do this on the client side with JavaScript.